# Chi-squared test for coherence test/pre-pruning

Tags: machine-learning, chi-squared-test, cart, online-algorithms

I am implementing the algorithm OnlineTree2 described in this [paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v8/nunez07a.html). OnlineTree2 is an on-line machine learning algorithm which builds a decision tree based on a stream of labelled examples. When a new example arrives at a node in the tree the node is checked for coherence with the underlying concept by using a chi-squared hypothesis test. In the paper it says:

> [...] in order to know if a node is coherent with a concept we use a χ2 hypothesis test (with a significance level of 0.05) between the examples distribution of the node under analysis and the sum of the class distributions of its descendant nodes.

How does this test work? I am able to compute the class distributions of the example in each node by just counting how many examples of each class pass that node. But if I just sum the distributions of the child nodes of a specific node I just get the same distribution as in the node above. What am I missing? I couldn't find a good source explaining the application of such a chi-squared test in a decision tree algorithm like that.